# Joins vs Populate | Lookup

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

According to [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) docs:

> MongoDB has the join-like $lookup aggregation operator in versions >= 3.2

I have to build a small API application for CRUD operations on the database, which database(SQL/NoSQL) would be better here. I am not sure, about the join-like queries provided.

Is it fast or slow, should I prefer NoSQL(as in mongoose) for these features?

Comment: Mongoose has a pretty powerful tool to implement the queries you are wondering about called populate. I suggest having a look at the official Mongoose docs and check that out.

Comment: I have used it in some applications, but a couple of folks said that it is not better but an alternative proposed as using NoSQL. If there even a graphical or any articles on the comparisons which explains it would be helpful.